# Help with the following series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Can anyone help me to find the value of the following series?

$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{1}{1+x^{2n}}\quad $ and $\quad \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{1}{n^{3/2}} \left(\dfrac{ x}{1+x}\right)^n$

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The second series is nothing but
$$\text{Li}_{3/2} \left(\dfrac{x}{1+x}\right)$$
since $$\text{Li}_s(a) = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{a^k}{k^s}$$ where $\text{Li}_s(a)$ is the [polylogarithm function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm).

The first series can also be written as follows (though it doesn't provide any "closed" form). We have
$$\dfrac1{1+x^{2n}} = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} (-1)^k x^{2kn}$$
Hence,
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\dfrac1{1+x^{2n}} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} (-1)^k x^{2kn} = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} (-1)^k \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} x^{2kn} = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \dfrac{(-1)^k}{1-x^{2k}}$$